# PowerShell: return error exit code if not match a string

Tags: powershell

I found that

`$(Invoke-Expression hostname) -eq 'mycomputername'`

Whether it is matched or not, the exitcode must be 0
this behavior is different from linux ,i.e, if not match error code exit 1

Is there any short command in PowerShell that can return error exit code if doesn't match the string?

Answer (score 31):

In an script you can change exit code using `exit` keyword.

A normal termination will set the exitcode to 0

An uncaught `THROW` will set the exitcode to 1

The `EXIT` statement will stop the process and set the exitcode to whatever is specified.

In your case I'ld do something like this

```
if ( $(hostname) -eq 'mycomputername')
{
  exit 0
}
else
{
  exit 1
}
```

Comment: An uncaught `THROW` did not set the exitcode to1 for me, on PowerShell v3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Minor update, you can simplify this these days:

```
powershell -command "if($(Invoke-Expression hostname) -ne 'wrongname'){ exit 1 }"
echo Error=%ERRORLEVEL%
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
C:\>powershell -command "& { if($(Invoke-Expression hostname) -eq 'wrongname'){ exit 0 } else { exit 1 }  } "
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\>powershell -command "& { if($(Invoke-Expression hostname) -eq 'rightname'){ exit 0 } else { exit 1 }  } "
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Comment: yes you are right is there any better way to do ? looks like very clusmy

Comment: @KitHo Might be. Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve? Streamlining depends on intended use case.

Comment: What i want to achieve is that compare the hostname , it is matched string, it will  return exit code 0, otherwise return exit code 1

Comment: @KitHo Look up the XY problem.

Comment: what do u mean XY problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting it more succint,

```
powershell -command "& { if($(Invoke-Expression hostname) -ne 'wrongname'){ exit 1 } }"
```